# How would I get a classes href below it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<li class="catalog-list-item" data-icon="false">
    <a href="/items/170893265">
```

How would I get the href /items/ and console.log the ID under catalog-list-item?
I tried parentNode and stuff, nothing seems to work for me.

Comment: please mention your code, showing what you did

Comment: You title and description not making sense!

Answer (score 1):

To log the `href` attribute, I'd do something like this

```
$(".catalog-list-item a").each(
   function(){
      console.log($(this).attr("href"));
   });
```

I don't completely catch the idea of logging the ID - there is no ID mentioned in your code example.

Comment: How would I do it like this? $.get("http://m.roblox.com/Catalog/CatalogSearch?startRow=0&keyword=&filter=Collectibles", function(Data){
      var yolo = $(Data).find(".catalog-list-item")
      console.log($(yolo).attr("href"));
   });

Answer (score 0):

By using jQuery selector ([jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)), you can retrieve all anchor tags that are children of an element with the '.catalog-list-item' class.

var allAnchorTags = $(".catalog-list-item a");

You can get the href attribute value by using [`.attr`-method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

With the [`.replace`-method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) you can replace the '/item/' string in front of the id.

Comment: I don't get the .replace, I have this so far. `$.get("http://m.roblox.com/Catalog/CatalogSearch?startRow=0&keyword=&filter=Collectibles", function(Data){
      var allAnchorTags = $(Data).find(".catalog-list-item a");
   var itemID = allAnchorTags.attr("href");
   
   });`

Comment: If you have further information to your question. Add those to the question, so everybody can see it.